# Stucked in the grub command prompt

Tags: grub2, windows

I have a windows xp os, and I ve decided to give ubuntu a shot. I installed and It when rebooting it did boot by default windows.
I red several forums and after entering those commands:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root -directory=/mnt/ubuntu
```

after rebooting the system showed me the command grub. And I cannot get anywhere.
I don t have a windows cd to fix anything. so how can I launch windows from this command grub?

Thanks... I am in a real mess.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it the (very) easy way download the boot repair disk and burn it to a cd, and boot from the cd.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've managed to bork the bootloader. Insert the live cd and follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal) to restore it using the live cd.

Comment: Thanks, yes.. i am stupid...lol. I ll try this.

Comment: Don't worry about messing things up, it's the best way to learn. I've stuffed the bootloader up many times in the past and it took me awhile to become confident enough in knowing that I could fix it whenever it broke.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you used EasyBCD to set up your dual-boot situation? This is what I had done (running Windows 7), and I suffered from a similar problem.

You need to boot to XP, upgrade EasyBCD to version 2.2, and then manually create a new entry for Linux using GRUB2. Version 2.2 of EasyBCD allows you to specify the Linux boot partition location for GRUB2, which older versions did not allow for.

Once you ensure that your new entry successfully boots you into Ubuntu 12.10, go back and delete the old entry.